# How do I read from a file that has the 0xEB character in it?

Tags: python

I have tried using `open("oxeb.txt").read()` in python 2 and it works but it doesn't work in python 3.

I know that the default encoding in python 2 is ascii and the default encoding in python 3 is utf8 so I tried doing this in python 3: `open("oxeb.txt").read()` and it STILL doesn't work.

How can I read a file with this character in it - independent of my python version?

Note: this is the error I get `UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xeb in position 4: invalid continuation byte`

Comment: @Austin I get the exact same error

Comment: In python3 you can use `open("oxeb.txt", encoding="ascii").read()` to read that file. But it is not independent as there is no `encoding` parameter in python2's `open`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can open the file in binary mode.
Obviously then you no longer have printable string data, but binary data.
So you will need to convert it.

```
text = open("oxeb.txt","rb").read()
text = text.decode('iso-8859-1')
```

Comment: I get the same error except it says 'ascii' can't decode the 0xeb byte rather than 'utf-8'.

Comment: Yes, indeed.  ASCII is technically 7-bits only.  The de-facto 8 bit ASCII became iso-8859-1.  I have updated the code.  There's also iso-8859-15 too (and others).